# Swap Kth node from beginning with Kth node from end in a Linked List

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

Given a singly linked list, swap kth node from beginning with kth node from end. Swapping of data is not allowed, only pointers should be changed.

[image: Diag]

This code is attributed to geeksforgeeks.  I'm looking for code-review, optimizations and best practices.

1. Why I don't extend or reuse: I am prepping for interviews, and interviewers explicitly want you to code, in my experience.  I request the reviewer to not insist on reusing, as I am aware in real life reusability is the right approach.  This does not work in interviews.
2. Why don't I use a `Util` class instead nesting method inside linked list?  That is because I need the `Node` to be an internal data structure.  Had I made a `Util` class, it would have no access to internal data structure and perform operations on the node's pointers.

```
public class SwapKth<T> {

    private Node<T> first;
    private int size;

    public SwapKth(List<T> items) {
        addAll(items);
    }

    private void addAll(List<T> items) {
        Node<T> prev = null;
        size = items.size();
        for (T item : items) {
            Node<T> node = new Node<T>(item);
            if (prev == null) {
                first = prev = node;
            } else {
                prev.next = node;
                prev = node;
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Node<T> {
        private Node<T> next;
        private T item;

        Node(T item) {
            this.item = item;
        }
    }

    public void swap (int n)  {
        if (n == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The value of n should be greater than 0.");
        }
        if (n > size) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The value of n: " + n + " is greater than: " + size);
        }

        // code to reach the nth node from front.
        Node<T> x = first;
        Node<T> prevX = null;
        for (int i = 0; x != null && i < (n - 1); x = x.next, i = i + 1) {
            prevX = x;
        }

        // code to reach the nth node from the end.
        Node<T> temp = x.next;  // note: we have x.next in place.
        Node<T> y = first; 
        Node<T> prevY = null;
        for (; temp != null; temp = temp.next, y = y.next) {
            prevY = y;
        } 

        // if 'x' and 'y' happen to be the same node.
        // eg: 1->2->3->4->5, swap 3rd from start with 3rd from the end.
        if (x == y) return;


        Node<T> prevFirst = null;
        Node<T> first = null;
        Node<T> prevSecond = null;
        Node<T> second = null;


        if (n <= size/2) { 
            prevFirst =  prevX; 
            first =  x;
            prevSecond = prevY; 
            second =  y;
        } else {
            prevFirst =  prevY;
            first =  y;
            prevSecond = prevX;    
            second = x;
        }



        if (first.next == second) {
            adjacentSwap(prevFirst, first, second);  
        } else {
            distantSwap(prevFirst, first, prevSecond, second);  
        }

    }


    /**
     * Swap 3rd from start with 3rd form the end, in a linkedlist like.
     * 1->2->3->4->5->6
     * Here node 3, and 4 are adjacent
     * 
     * Edge case:  
     * 1->2          (swap 1 with 2)
     */
    public void adjacentSwap(Node<T> firstPrev, Node<T> first, Node<T> second) {
        first.next = second.next;
        second.next = first;
        if (firstPrev != null) {
            firstPrev.next = second;
        } else {
            this.first = second;
        }
    }



    /**
     * Swap 2nd not from the front and 2nd node from the end.
     * 1->2->3->4->5->6
     * Here node 2nd node and 5th node are not adjacent
     * 
     * Edge case:
     * 1->2->3->4->5->6 (swap 1 with 6)
     * 
     */
    public void distantSwap(Node<T> firstPrev, Node<T> first, Node<T> secondPrev, Node<T> second) {
        if (firstPrev != null) {
            firstPrev.next = first.next;
            secondPrev.next = second.next;

            second.next = firstPrev.next;
            first.next = secondPrev.next;

            firstPrev.next = second;
            secondPrev.next = first;
        } else {
            secondPrev.next = second.next;

            second.next = first.next;
            first.next = secondPrev.next;

            this.first = second;
            secondPrev.next = first;
        }
    }

    // size of new linkedlist is unknown to us, in such a case simply return the list rather than an array.
    public List<T> toList() {
        final List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (first == null) return list;

        for (Node<T> x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
            list.add(x.item);
        }

        return list;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hashCode = 1;
        for (Node<T> x = first; x != null; x = x.next)
            hashCode = 31*hashCode +  (x.item == null ? 0 : x.hashCode());
        return hashCode;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        SwapKth<T> other = (SwapKth<T>) obj;
        Node<T> currentListNode = first; 
        Node<T> otherListNode =  other.first;

        while (currentListNode != null && otherListNode != null) {
            if (currentListNode.item != otherListNode.item) return false;
            currentListNode = currentListNode.next;
            otherListNode = otherListNode.next;
        }
        return currentListNode == null && otherListNode == null;
    }
}


public class SwapKthTest {

    @Test
    public void testEvenLength() {
        SwapKth<Integer> sk1 = new SwapKth<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
        sk1.swap(1);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1), sk1.toList());

        SwapKth<Integer> sk2 = new SwapKth<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
        sk2.swap(2);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 6), sk2.toList());

        SwapKth<Integer> sk3 = new SwapKth<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
        sk3.swap(3);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6), sk3.toList());

        SwapKth<Integer> sk4 = new SwapKth<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
        sk4.swap(4);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6), sk4.toList()); 

        SwapKth<Integer> sk5 = new SwapKth<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
        sk5.swap(5);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 6), sk2.toList());

        SwapKth<Integer> sk6 = new SwapKth<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
        sk6.swap(6);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1), sk6.toList()); 
    }

    @Test
    public void testOddLength() {
        SwapKth<Integer> sk7 = new SwapKth<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
        sk7.swap(1);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(5, 2, 3, 4, 1), sk7.toList());

        SwapKth<Integer> sk8 = new SwapKth<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
        sk8.swap(2);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(1, 4, 3, 2, 5), sk8.toList());

        SwapKth<Integer> sk9 = new SwapKth<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
        sk9.swap(3);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), sk9.toList());

        SwapKth<Integer> sk10 = new SwapKth<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
        sk10.swap(4);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(1, 4, 3, 2, 5), sk10.toList());

        SwapKth<Integer> sk11 = new SwapKth<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
        sk11.swap(5);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(5, 2, 3, 4, 1), sk11.toList());
    }

    @Test
    public void testTwoElement() {
        SwapKth<Integer> sk12 = new SwapKth<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2));
        sk12.swap(1);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(2, 1), sk12.toList()); 

        SwapKth<Integer> sk13 = new SwapKth<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2));
        sk13.swap(2);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(2, 1), sk13.toList()); 
    }

    @Test
    public void testSingleElement() {
        SwapKth<Integer> sk14 = new SwapKth<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1));
        sk14.swap(1); 
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(1), sk14.toList()); 
    }

}
```

Comment: You're not threadsafe in case that's an issue.

Answer (score 5):

Realize that when \$n > size / 2\$, it's equivalent to \$n = size - n + 1\$. That is, in a list of 6 elements, swapping with `n=6` should be the same as `n=1`. As a result, this code can be simplified:

> ```
> Node<T> prevFirst = null;
> Node<T> first = null;
> Node<T> prevSecond = null;
> Node<T> second = null;
>
> if (n <= size/2) { 
>     prevFirst =  prevX; 
>     first =  x;
>     prevSecond = prevY; 
>     second =  y;
> } else {
>     prevFirst =  prevY;
>     first =  y;
>     prevSecond = prevX;    
>     second = x;
> }
>
> if (first.next == second) {
>     adjacentSwap(prevFirst, first, second);  
> } else {
>     distantSwap(prevFirst, first, prevSecond, second);  
> }
> ```

To this:

```
if (n > size / 2) {
    n = size - n + 1;
}

// ... the code finding `prevX`, `x`, `prevY`, `y`, `prevY`

if (x.next == y) {
    adjacentSwap(prevX, x, y);
} else {
    distantSwap(prevX, x, prevY, y);
}
```

---

This loop can be simplified a bit:

> ```
> for (int i = 0; x != null && i < (n - 1); x = x.next, i = i + 1) {
>     prevX = x;
> }
> ```

You don't need the null check on `x`, thanks to the validation on `n` with respect to `size` at the beginning of the method. Also you should write `++i` instead of `i = i + 1`, and no need for the parentheses in `i < (n - 1)`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; x = x.next, ++i) {
    prevX = x;
}
```

---

In this code, you're effectively iterating from the beginning until the `size - n + 1`-th node.

> ```
> Node<T> temp = x.next;  // note: we have x.next in place.
> Node<T> y = first; 
> Node<T> prevY = null;
> for (; temp != null; temp = temp.next, y = y.next) {
>     prevY = y;
> }
> ```

But you don't have to: you have already iterated until the n-th, and to reach the \$(size - n + 1)\$-th node, you only need to iterate over \$size - 2 * n + 1\$ items, which can be far less than going from the beginning:

```
Node<T> y = x;
Node<T> prevY = null;
for (int i = 0; i < size - 2 * n + 1; ++i, y = y.next) {
    prevY = y;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Not mentioned elsewhere:**

Dial back on the excessive use of new lines. Readability is important but remember that scrolling impairs readability as well so try to keep your code a bit tighter (but not too tight!).

Why are `adjacentSwap` and `distantSwap` public functions? You're not testing them in the unit tests and they make no sense to be public to me.

I believe that you should extract the node finding in the `swap` method to functions.